# Spacemacs: How do I navigate between folders?

Tags: ide, spacemacs

This is probably a trivial question, but I cannot find any info on this. I have never used vim nor emacs before. I have completed the evil tutorial and I have played a little bit with `SPC-` commands. But I couldn't find anywhere how should I navigate between folders...

I tried: `:! cd ...` but it didn't work.

Comment: As a side note: I would greatly appreciate some link on more advanced tutorial for spacemacs that covers these topics because I feel ashamed to ask such beginner questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You go into command mode (pressing `:` in evil-mode) and enter

`edit ~/projects/foobar`

when it`s recognized by helm projectile (git projects are recognized automatically, otherwise you have to define a projectile file), you will be later able to switch between projects, you once have opened, by pressing

`SPC p p`

also you can switch between recent open files with

`SPC b b`

you can search those commands by pressing `M-x` (M stays for `alt`)